# samsung 10.1 galaxy tablet is not handling the media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

My question is that media queries is working fine in all the devices but the problem is coming in samsung glaxay tab10.1 while it is working fine in ipad etc please check my media queries

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape)

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait)
```

Comment: did you get the answer?

Comment: Similar to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60332544/12936509 This works for me

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 resolution is 800x1280 and you're looking for devices between 768x1024 so this wont work

ideally you should do mobile first and something similar to these media queries

```
@media screen (min-width: 480px) {
    //css goes here
}

@media screen (min-width: 768px) {
    //css goes here
}

@media screen (min-width: 1024px) {
    //css goes here
}
```