# CSS3 Media Queries - Galaxy Tab2 and iPad conflict

Tags: css, media-queries

Guys there's a problem with media queries targeting iPad and Samsung Galaxy Tab2. Media Queries i wrote for SGT2 are over-riding iPad ones.

Media Query I'm using for iPad -

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {}
```

For Galaxy Tab2 -

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 600px) and (max-device-width : 768px) and (orientation : portrait) {}
```

Is there any way i can avoid this conflict?

Comment: Not sure just an idea. SInce iphone are 2X devices. Y dont u try aiming at retina display's with this media query @media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}. Not sure whether it will work for u

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media Query for iPad (Landscape) applied to Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (Landscape) as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209921/media-query-for-ipad-landscape-applied-to-samsung-galaxy-tab-2-landscape-as)